# How to solve tput problem when installing drush on Windows?

Tags: drush

I am trying to get Drush running on my local development site. Drush & Cygwin are installed and the cygwin command prompt responds to Drush commands such as "Drush topic" but precedes the command output with:

> "which: no tput in + a long list of directory paths"

and then gives the topic list.  When I respond with 16 (Drupal help for error messages) I get:

> fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource [warning]
>   output.inc:29

I believe I have to add path definitions, but am not certain where to define them.  My current configuration on a windows OS has apache & php under C:/Program Files/acquai drupal/ (I used their setup for php and apache, but not their Drupal Site setup.)  I have Drush located under C:/Drush and my site located under `C:/Documents and Settings/admin/my-site`.

Comment: wasn't able to put comment, however, this also helps:
[How can I find a missing binary needed under Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/362884/how-can-i-find-a-missing-binary-needed-under-cygwin)

Answer (score 3):

Ashlar seems to have found a solution to the tput problem in his own bug report 'by adding the add-on gygwin command tput from the cygwin installation program "setup.exe". The actual command i not on the list. Look for the "ncurses" package which includes the Tput utility.' ... see http://drupal.org/node/1361510#comment-5327144

Comment: +1 Hey Thanks.  I forgot to come back here when I worked it out, I appreciate your catching that!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Drush Windows Installer](https://github.com/drushonwindows/Drush-on-Windows-Installer) ([old instructions](http://web.archive.org/web/20140912220827/http://drush.ws/drush_windows_installer)).

This package installs a standalone Drush, and adjust the Windows PATH to point to itself and its supporting executables. You can use this to learn how to set the PATH.

Comment: Thanks, That is what I used to install Drush in the first place.  I reinstalled it, but no change.  I submitted the problem as a bug report, so we'll see if they have any ideas.

Comment: OK. Also, I did get to my Drush Windows environment, and tried "drush topic", selecting item 16. I was able to see your error. Good luck with the issue!